# Multiple location filters

Tags: filter, here-api, here-maps-rest, here-autocomplete

I would like to be able to send requests with multiple 'circle-filters' or 'bounding box-filters'. For example:

```
autosuggest?in=ONE-CIRCLE;ANOTHER-CIRCLE&q=some street

autosuggest?in=
59.33563802356494,18.067049995800794;r=15000;
82.35453453543,17.456456456;r=15000
&q=some street
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? If yes - then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently supported through the API. You could fire off two API calls, one for each circle and then merge the results. (I get that the merging can be a bit of extra work and could possible slow down the response time to key pressed as well, but it's the best I can think of.)